# Unity OnTriggerEnter2D() not responding

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This Is a bug that I've been trying to solve for about 2 hours, and yet to no avail. I've read pretty much EVERY single post about this but anyways here's my code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy_Sideways : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]private float damage;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        Debug.Log("AA");
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            Debug.Log("Right now I am the shell of my former body");
        }
    }
}
```

Here are all the ways **I have already tried using**:

```
-Spelling
-RigidBody2D
-RigidBody2D(not-kinematic)
```

Comment: Both GameObjects must contain a Collider component. One must have Collider.isTrigger enabled, and contain a Rigidbody. If both GameObjects have Collider.isTrigger enabled, no collision happens. The same applies when both GameObjects do not have a Rigidbody component.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Your code is in `c#`

Answer (score 0):

Any one should have rigidBody2D and 2d colliders works with 2D only, or try reloading project

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I now noticed what I did wrong( a very stupid miscalculation ) but in order to help people I will post this. I forgot to add the Box Collider 2D method. I fully blame myself.